# What happens if I call serviceWorker.register multiple times?

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I am trying to integrate Web Push notification via a push notification service provider.

I am already calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register` on all pages. The service provider's script is loaded only when the user has interacted with the site. The script again calls `navigator.serviceWorker.register`.

What happens when a page registers the same service worker script twice (with identical arguments)? Will it re-use the existing registration, or cause a re-registration? Are there any disadvantages to registering a service worker multiple times from a page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` as frequently or infrequently as you like, assuming you use the same arguments each time. The promise that it returns will resolve with an equivalent `ServiceWorkerRegistration` each time.

Multiple calls (either during the same browsing session, or across multiple browsing sessions) don't have any effect—[subsequent calls are effectively a no-op](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/registration#subsequent_visits).